# Image not uploaded

Tags: product, image, products, magento-1.9, media

I am using Magento Version 1.9.0.1. When I tried to upload an image for a product I get below error.

I tried reinstalling Magento, but that didn't work.

Please help me to identify the problem and fix it.

[image]

Comment: Is the image larger than max allowed upload?

Comment: @Marius no just 110.45 kb

Comment: upload_max_filesize 2M 2M  
upload_tmp_dir  /tmp /tmp

Comment: Check file permissions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a number of things to consider before checking logs (which you should do anyway):

1. Is your upload_max_filesize big enough?
2. What are the privileges of your media folder (your server must be able to write there, otherwise no uploads)?
3. Do you have enough space either in PHP tmp catalog or media catalog?
4. Do you have enough inodes?
5. Do you have file upload enabled at all (perhaps you have file_uploads=Off)?

Comment: Max upload size is 2M. Media folder privileges are 770. There is free space in tmp folder. I am not sure about inodes. file_uploads=ON.

Comment: I have unlimited disk space on an VPS.

Comment: our server php info can be found here. http://stellarthoughts.in/info.php

Comment: There's VERY good chance that either your web server is not the owner of this folder, or it doesn't belong to the group which has rights for this folder. 770 means that owner and group has all privileges and everyone else has none.

Comment: @brainless How u solved your file upload issue , as same i am facing , i checked as suggested by `Pronto`